# how to set the checkbox(mark task complete) option in task list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, task-list

I have task list but I didn't find the checkbox (mark task complete) option in my task list.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: You can add it by modifying your view. You can get it by "Completed" column in your view

Comment: I already modified the view i set completed column, but it's shows the Yes/no options only not checkboxs.

Comment: Have you made that list from code?

Comment: No it's ootb task list. lot of research i have to done. i got option like in list view web we have  option  miscellaneous there one option "server render". is it works or not. help me

Comment: This link may help you. https://spandps.com/2013/12/05/sharepoint-2013-mark-task-complete/

Comment: I would say try to create another tasklist and check it if it comes or note

Answer (score 1):

It is the `Completed` column in a Tasks list that is displayed as the Checkbox.

If you, instead, see the Yes/No values it means the needed (SharePoint) JavaScript `hierarchytaskslist.js` was **not** executed on the ListView.

One scenario can be you have attached JSLinks on the **WebPart**, this prevents execution of any JS files attached to the **View** definition
As seen in the screenshot below of a standard Tasks list; all Views make that Completed column work *until a JSLink is set on the WebPart*

Solution is to add the `hierarchytaskslist.js` to the JSLinks of the **WebPart**
*not done yet in the screenshot below*

The https://365csi.nl/icsr/linkmanager/ helps with managing JSLinks
, if you click 'or select a JavaScript file' on the WebPart row, you can add the required `hierarchytaskslist.js` with one click.

[image]